# How to make bazel print less?

Tags: bazel

When I run tests using bazel it outputs something like:

```
endobson@yggdrasil () ~/proj/racket/yaspl2 % ibazel test //libraries/... //tools/...                                                                                                                                                      (3)
Testing //libraries/... //tools/...
INFO: Analysed 466 targets (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 431 targets and 35 test targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.296s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
//libraries:byte-escapes-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries:fill-stack-test                                     (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries:large-function-test                                 (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:lexer-test                                          (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:module-signature-serialization-test                 (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:pretty-print-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:resolved-imports-language-test                      (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:sexp-parser-test                                    (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:sexp-printer-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:tail-call-test                                      (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries:type-checker-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:type-unification-test                               (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:types-test                                          (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/algorithms:depth-first-search-test                  (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:bytes-test                                     (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries/data:dict-test                                      (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:list-test                                      (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries/data:maybe-test                                     (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:red-black-tree-test                            (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:regexp-test                                    (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:set-test                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries/data:tuples-test                                    (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language:color-graph-test                      (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language:lower-x86-64-test                     (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:call1_test                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:call2_test                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:call3_test                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:cast1_test                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:exit_test                    (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:factorial_test               (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:hello-world_test             (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:pointers1_test               (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:pointers2_test               (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:pointers3_test               (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language/examples:spill_test                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
```

This is a large amount of text and take up most of my laptop screen. When there are build errors they end up above all the tests that failed. E.g.

```
Testing //libraries/... //tools/...
INFO: Analysed 466 targets (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 431 targets and 35 test targets...
ERROR: /Users/endobson/proj/racket/yaspl2/libraries/BUILD:441:1: Couldn't build file libraries/mach-o-writer_lib.o: YasplCompile libraries/mach-o-writer_lib.o failed (Exit 1)
Not a valid argument
ERROR: /Users/endobson/proj/racket/yaspl2/libraries/BUILD:441:1: Couldn't build file libraries/mach-o-writer_lib.o: YasplCompile libraries/mach-o-writer_lib.o failed (Exit 1)
Not a valid argument
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.356s, Critical Path: 0.04s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
//libraries:byte-escapes-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries:fill-stack-test                                     (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries:large-function-test                                 (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:lexer-test                                          (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:module-signature-serialization-test                 (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:pretty-print-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:resolved-imports-language-test                      (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:sexp-parser-test                                    (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:sexp-printer-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:tail-call-test                                      (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries:type-checker-test                                   (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:type-unification-test                               (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries:types-test                                          (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/algorithms:depth-first-search-test                  (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:bytes-test                                     (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries/data:dict-test                                      (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:list-test                                      (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries/data:maybe-test                                     (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:red-black-tree-test                            (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:regexp-test                                    (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/data:set-test                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//libraries/data:tuples-test                                    (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language:color-graph-test                      (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//libraries/prim-language:lower-x86-64-test                     (cached) PASSED in 0.2s

Executed 0 out of 35 tests: 24 tests pass and 11 fail to build.
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
```

Is there a way to hide all of the "PASSED" test targets and only output build and test failures, and possibly a summary line at the bottom? None of the documented verbosity options that I tried seemed to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've tried. `--test_output=errors --noshow_progress` works well for me with at least 0.12.0.

```
bazel --batch test --jobs 2 --test_output=errors --noshow_progress --test_timeout=300,300,900,3600 //...
```

Comment: Those flags don't remove the "PASSED" lines for me. `bazel --bazelrc=/dev/null test //libraries/... //tools/... --test_output=errors --noshow_progress`. Running with 0.12.0.

Comment: Nope, I hadn't. That seems to be the flag I was looking for. Filed https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5149 to get it categorized in the right section of flags.